# (Python3.11) Receiving data from Serial Connection Delayed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still fairly new to python, and I'm busy with a serial communication program.
I have two problems.

**Problem 1:**
There seems to be a delay almost in received data, or almost like some data is stuck.  I have a keypad which I connect via the serial port, and when you press a button, the serial port replies with BUTTON=0 through BUTTON=12.

- However when I press the first button, it seems that any other received data comes through first.
- Then you press the first button again, then BUTTON=0 will show.
- But when I go to button 1, then you have to press button 1 twice.  On the first press it will show BUTTON=0 and on the second press it will show BUTTON=1

And so it will go on through all the buttons.

**Problem 2:**
Another small problem I'm encountering, which is weird, is that sometimes the text_area doesn't scroll down properly with the last bit of received data, I literally have to scroll down with the mouse to see what happened.

this is the code I am using.  Any help would be appreciated:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import serial
from serial.tools import list_ports
from serial.serialutil import SerialException
import re

class SerialThread(QThread):
    received_data = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, port, baudrate):
        super().__init__()
        self.port = port
        self.baudrate = baudrate

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        try:
            self.ser = serial.Serial(port=self.port,
                            baudrate=self.baudrate,
                            bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                            rtscts=False, xonxoff=False,
                            dsrdtr=False)
            while self.running:
                if self.ser.in_waiting > 0:
                    data = self.ser.readline().decode('latin-1', errors='replace').strip()
                    self.received_data.emit(data)
        except serial.SerialException as e:
            print(f"Serial port error: {e}")

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        if self.ser:
            self.ser.close()

    def send_data(self, data):
        if self.ser:
            self.ser.write(data.encode('latin-1'))

class Main_GridLayout(QWidget):
    send_data_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ccid_value = ""
        self.msisdn_value = ""
        self.imei_value = ""
        self.build_widgets()
        self.build_layout()

    def build_widgets(self):

        self.com_ports = [port.device for port in list_ports.comports()]
        self.com_ports_combo = QComboBox()
        self.com_ports_combo.setFixedSize(100, 25)
        self.com_ports_combo.addItem("Select COM")
        self.com_ports_combo.addItems(self.com_ports)

        self.btn_mainconnect = QPushButton(text="Connect")
        self.commactive = False
        self.btn_mainconnect.clicked.connect(self.left_connect)
        self.btn_mainconnect.setFixedSize(100, 25)

        self.text_area = QTextEdit()
        self.text_area.setReadOnly(True)
        self.text_area.setFixedSize(600, 600)
        self.text_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        self.label_msisdn = QLabel("MSISDN: ")
        self.current_msisdn = QLineEdit()
        self.current_msisdn.setStyleSheet("background: transparent; border: 0px;")
        self.current_msisdn.setText(str(self.msisdn_value))
        self.current_msisdn.setReadOnly(True)
        self.label_ccid = QLabel("CCID: ")
        self.current_ccid = QLineEdit()
        self.current_ccid.setStyleSheet("background: transparent; border: 0px;")
        self.current_ccid.setText(str(self.ccid_value))
        self.current_ccid.setReadOnly(True)
        self.label_imei = QLabel("IMEI: ")
        self.current_imei = QLineEdit()
        self.current_imei.setStyleSheet("background: transparent; border: 0px;")
        self.current_imei.setText(str(self.imei_value))
        self.current_imei.setReadOnly(True)

        self.bottomcon = QWidget()
        self.bottomcon_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.bottomcon.setLayout(self.bottomcon_layout)
        self.bottomcon_layout.addWidget(self.label_msisdn)
        self.bottomcon_layout.addWidget(self.current_msisdn)
        self.bottomcon_layout.addWidget(self.label_ccid)
        self.bottomcon_layout.addWidget(self.current_ccid)
        self.bottomcon_layout.addWidget(self.label_imei)
        self.bottomcon_layout.addWidget(self.current_imei)

    def build_layout(self):
        self.container = QFrame()
        grid_layout = QGridLayout(self.container)

        # Add the combo box to the layout
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.com_ports_combo, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.btn_mainconnect, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.text_area, 1, 1, 20, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.bottomcon, 21, 1, 1, 1)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.container)
        self.container.setFixedHeight(self.container.sizeHint().height())

    def left_connect(self):

        selected_port = self.com_ports_combo.currentText()

        if self.commactive:
            self.commactive = False
            self.btn_mainconnect.setText("Connect")
            self.stop_communication()
            return

        if selected_port == "Select COM":
            self.comm_port_active = False
        else:
            self.comm_port_active = True
            self.commactive = True

        if not self.comm_port_active:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "COM PORT ERROR", "Select COM Port and click the connect button.")
            return

        try:
            ser = serial.Serial(selected_port)
            ser.close()
        except SerialException:
            self.comm_port_active = False
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", f"Port {selected_port} is already open")
            return

        if self.commactive:
            self.btn_mainconnect.setText("Disconnect")
            self.start_communication()


    def start_communication(self):
        selected_port = self.com_ports_combo.currentText()
        selected_baud_rate = int(115200)
        self.serial_thread = SerialThread(selected_port, selected_baud_rate)
        self.serial_thread.received_data.connect(self.update_text_area)
        self.serial_thread.start()
        self.send_data_signal.connect(self.serial_thread.send_data)

    def stop_communication(self):
        if self.serial_thread.isRunning():
            self.serial_thread.stop()
        self.communication_active = False

    def update_text_area(self, data):
        self.text_area.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
        self.text_area.append(data)

def main():
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    print("default-style: ", app.style().metaObject().className())
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    mainwindow = Main_GridLayout()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```